# How do I get an enum's structure component in Rust?

Tags: rust, enums

How can I print an enum's structure component. E.g. below I just want to print the value of `click.x` instead of the complete `click` structure.

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
    enum WebEvent {
        // or c-like structures.
        Click { x: i64, y: i64 },
    }

    let click = WebEvent::Click { x: 22, y: 33 };
    println!("{:?}", click);  // how do I print click.x ?
}
```

Comment: Ok it is close. I ve solved it using your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link by John C I figured it out. Kind of weird way of doing it but it works. If anyone else has better way would like to hear it. Thanks.

```
#![allow(unused)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
enum WebEvent {
    // or c-like structures.
    Click { x: i64, y: i64 },
}

fn main() {
    let click = WebEvent::Click { x: 22, y: 33 };

    let WebEvent::Click{x, y} = click;
    println!("Extracted x = {}, and y = {}", x, y);
   
}
```

Comment: In this case since your `enum` has only a single variant, you can get rid of the `if`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=8d736fb9fc070e458579a36e510128a7)

Comment: I updated the code into something that *might* look less confusing. I will admit it still looks odd to me, extracting data from an Enum. But Enums are just not objects with parameters attached - they are a combination of multiple types of data structures, and you have to reference (destructure) the specific type of an assigned Enum.

Comment: Now this makes sense. Didn't realize you can deconstruct it like that.  By the way edited/removed an extraneous }. But thanks for your answers.